# Can not login into google account because of "insufficient browser" error using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, google-signin

I have bunch of google account where I need to login and get apps ids from developer console. Within around 30 accounts I have 3 accounts where I can not login getting message "You are trying to sign in from a browser or app that doesn't allow us to keep your account secure." after input of login and password. With manually started browser I can login into this account as usual.
All accounts logins shares same steps:
1. Open login page
2. Input email
3. Press 'Next'
4. Input password
5. Press 'Next'

27 accounts passes well but 3 exact accounts shows the following:
[image]

[Learn more leading here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en) and suggests possible reasons:

```
Don’t support JavaScript or have Javascript turned off.
Have unsecure or unsupported extensions added.
Use automation testing frameworks.
Are embedded in a different application.
```

All of these cases shared for all accounts so I don't think any of them match my issue

What I've done:
1. Side by side checked settings of developer.google.com, myaccount.google.com, console.developer.google.com pages. Found that accounts with login issue had 'API access' enabled but when I disabled it, it did not help
2. Found recommendation to enable 'Less secure apps' setting, but it did not help also
3. Tried to compare requests headers from selenium controlled browser and when I login manually - manually opened  browser sends 'DNT:1' (do not track) header - not sure how to check it for now. Can it be the issue and why probably selenium does not send it while 'regualar' browser does?
4. Also I have unsigned extensionfor proxifying requests via proxies with basic auth but it is common for both 'good' an 'bad' accounts
5. Google search does not help much - very few of results without any robust solutions
6. I am using Firefox ESR 68, also tried to user Firefox ESR 60. I have to use ESR build to install unsigned extension for proxies.

Login function looks like:

```
def google_login(driver, account):
    driver.get(GOOGLE_UI_LOGIN_URL)
    for letter in account['login']:
        driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(letter)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    for letter in account['password']:  # tried to emulate user behavior
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#password > div > div> div > input').send_keys(letter)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    try:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ZFr60d.CeoRYc')[0].click()
        print(f'{account["login"]} confirmed phone')
    except (WebDriverException, AttributeError, IndexError):
        pass
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'gwt-uid-276')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f'{account["login"]} failed to login')
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
I found workaround solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class Google:

 def __init__(self,username,password):
  self.driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Dragan/AppData/Local/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
  self.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent")
  sleep(3)
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="openid-buttons"]/button[1]').click()
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]').send_keys(username)
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]').click()
  sleep(3)
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(password)
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]').click()
  sleep(2)
  self.driver.get('https://youtube.com')
  sleep(5)

passw=open('New Text Document (2).txt',"r",encoding="utf-8")   
password=str(passw.read())
user=open('New Text Document (3).txt',"r",encoding="utf-8")   
username=str(user.read())
mylike= Google(username,password)
```

If you want to hide that your browser is selenium it is so hard, trust me. At least you need to rebuild chromium from source. It is google security system. And for some accounts google do not let login via selenium. And sometimes it is account problem. I think you can try more old/new accounts and google let you login. If you want to use different accounts only way to build your own 'fixed' chromium and controll it via selenium. And if you try login more (In my experience about 500 logins per day) from 1 ip adress and selenium them all can be banned by google. Multiple logins from selenium browser and 1 ip looks like malicious activity. Possession of multiple accounts is directly prohibited by Google’s rules. To get around these limitations, you can use different tricks. Just for example, perhaps you need to use various user agents, proxies and browser ids. This protection cannot be turned off, but it can be avoided if you do not need more accounts. And once again I warn you, logins from one browser and ip can lead to the ban of all your accounts.
To use proxies you can use my code for mozilla:

```
def setprefs(profile, proxy="", port=""):
    if proxy != "":
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", proxy)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", int(port))
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)

    profile.set_preference("dom.maxHardwareConcurrency", randrange(1, 8) * 2)


    oscpu = ["","","","","","","Win64; x64","WOW64"]

    platform = ["","","","win32","win32","win32","win32","win32","win32","win32","i686 on x86_64","Intel Mac OS X 10.11","PPC Mac OS X", "Windows NT", "Windows NT 5.1",
              "Windows NT 6.1", "Windows NT 6.1","Windows NT 6.1","Windows NT 6.2","Windows NT 6.2","Windows NT 6.2",
              "Windows NT 6.3","Windows NT 6.3","Windows NT 6.3","Windows NT 10.0","Windows NT 10.0",
              "Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12",
              "Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11",
              "Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9","Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8","X11; Linux","X11; Ubuntu; Linux","WOW64","Win64; x64",""]
    profile.set_preference("general.oscpu.override", random.choice(oscpu))
    profile.set_preference("general.platform.override", str(random.choice(platform)))

    profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID", "1234512345")
    profile.set_preference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US, en, ru-RU, ru")
    return profile
```

Comment: also google can check some other prefs. Looks in my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `args: ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir', '--allow-running-insecure-content' ]` to my config resolved the issue.
PS - I was using Protractor for my automation.

I realized later that this was not what helped me out as I tried with a different email and it didn't work. After some observations, I figured something else out and this has been tried and tested.

**Using automation**:

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login
Select Log in with Google Strategy
Enter Google username and password
Login to Stackoverflow
Go to https://gmail.com (or whatever Google app you want to access)

After doing this consistently for like a whole day (about 24 hours), try automating your login directly to gmail (or whatever Google app you want to access) directly... I've had at least two other people do this with success.
PS - You might want to continue with the stackoverflow login until you at least get a captcha request as we all went through that phase as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be because of the code.
It's a "feature" to keep your account "secure" .
You can try and change the user agent or change browser and see if that helps.

Comment: I think that if it is a feature it may be disableable. If some accounts affected by it and some are not. May be someone could help to find where this feature is controlled. Myself I am not able to find how to disable the feature

Comment: Also may be I can configure selenium or webdriver instance somehow to evade effect of the "feature"